# Create regular expression to get rid of illegal character patterns in PHP

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, what is a list of potentially harmful characters that can be used to break a PHP page? And, using regular expressions, how can I filter out the bad sequence of characters from all of my user input?

For example.. to check if a email is valid I would use the below line:

```
preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",$email);
```

This above checks for the specific pattern of the email.

But, just like when you check if a email is Valid using a regular expression, how would I check if the input has any invalid character patterns using one expression for every input? I would like to place this line at the very top of my php page which accepts a `$_GET` or `$_POST` to prevent any hacker-like inputs from crashing the page.

Hope this makes sense.
Thank you
PG

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that regular expression for validating e-mail is incomplete.  It will disallow perfectly valid e-mail addresses like John+Doe@example.com

Comment: +1 to VoteyDisciple's comment. Incomplete email validation schemes like this are some of the most annoying design decisions I ever come across.

Comment: wow you are right! Thank you for the feedback. How would I change this to fix the issue?

Comment: Don't try too hard to validate e-mail addresses; it's a lot more complicated than you think — see http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html . A better approach is: if it's got an @ and a . in it, it's an e-mail address.

Comment: I always use something like `/^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/` for validating e-mail addresses: one `@` sign, and at least one `.` after it.  It's wildly liberal in what it accepts (including invalid addresses like `.@.....`) but if someone is *that* determined to submit bogus data, no regular expression will stop them anyway, and this way I'm not rejecting anything valid while still catching obvious errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "one and only" way of filtering input like you describe, since no input is inherently invalid or even necessarily malicious.  It's entirely what you *do* with the input that matters.

For example, suppose you have some text in `$_GET['field']` and you are about to compose a SQL query.  You need to *escape* the value using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (for MySQL, of course) like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['field']) . "')";
```

This escaping is absolutely crucial to apply to input that you're using in a SQL query.  Once it's applied as you see here, even malicious input from a hacker will have no ill effects on your database.

However, this function is both useless and outright *wrong* to use if you're including `$_GET['field]` in some HTML output from your page.  In that case, the function `htmlspecialchars()` is useful.  You might do something like:

```
echo "<p>Your comments were: " . htmlspecialchars($_GET['field']) . "</p>";
```

Both these examples are quite safe from "hacker-like inputs."  You will not be inserting malicious data into your database or into your HTML.  Yet, notice the two forms of escaping are completely different functions, each suited to its use.

By contrast, imagine if you tried to "validate" input for these two uses at the same time.  You certainly couldn't allow `<` or `>` characters, since those could be part of a malicious HTML attack like Cross-Site Scripting.  So, visitors who want to write "I think 1 < 3" would be stymied.  Likewise, you couldn't allow quote marks for fear of malicious SQL injection attacks, so poor "Miles O'Brien" could never fill out your form!

Proper input *escaping* is very easy to do, as you use it in different contexts (it's often even easier than validating input!) yet the results are so much better.

Comment: +1. Domain-specific escaping is the right way to deal with ‘special’ characters. ‘sanitization’ and ‘verification’ are not.

Answer (score 0):

There are much better ways to clean input. The built-in function strip_tags will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about user input that will contain HTML characters and/or SQL injection types of attacks, look into the built-in PHP functions like htmlentities() and mysql_real_escape_string().

Please read the the docs for details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php